# Bootstrap - Let the specified <li> tag open when data-toggle="collapse"

Tags: html, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

I wanted to let the "Data Management" li to be opened by default if it's child has a class  "active".

Example in JSfiddle:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/5622/
```

HTML:

```
<div class="span4 well well-small">
            <ul id="action-menu" class="nav nav-list">
                <li class="nav-header">Navigation</li>
                <li ><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>admin" class=""><i class="icon-th"></i> Overview </a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#datamanagement-child" data-toggle="collapse"><i class="icon-book"></i> Data Management</a>
                    <ul id="datamanagement-child" class="nav nav-list collapse">
                        <li class="active"><a href="<?php base_url();?>admin/company" id="company-dm"><i class="icon-folder-close"></i> Company</a></li>
                        <li><a href="<?php base_url();?>admin/employee"><i class="icon-user"></i> Employee</a></li>
                        <li><a href="<?php base_url();?>admin/department"><i class="icon-home"></i> Department</a></li>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url() . "admin/position";?>"><i class="icon-indent-right"></i> Position</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#timekeeping-child" data-toggle="collapse"><i class="icon-time" ></i> Time keeping</a>
                    <ul id="timekeeping-child" class="nav nav-list collapse">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-edit"></i> Log employee</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-th-list"></i> Show logs</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-briefcase"></i> Accounts</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-list-alt"></i> Reports</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution 1

You can simply simulate a `click()` on data-management hash. This will make the toggle animation, too.

```
$("[href='#datamanagement-child']").click();
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/5623/)

### Solution 2

Add `in` class for the `ul` after data-management.

```
 <ul id="datamanagement-child" class="nav nav-list in collapse">
     ...
 </ul>
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/5624/)

The result is like in the screen shot bellow:

> [image]

Comment: @Bajongskie Yes, the first one is a little bit hacky (cliking on a link). You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you **only** want it to be open if it has a **child li with the class of "active"**, you can use this bit of jQuery that initiates the bootstrap collapse function if the active class is found:

```
if($("#datamanagement-child li.active").is("*")) {
     $("#datamanagement-child").collapse("show");
}
```

OR if you just want it to show without the slide effect, you can use this code:

```
if($("#datamanagement-child li.active").is("*")) {
     $("#datamanagement-child").addClass("in");
}
```

Any of the above code would need to go within your:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

// Code Here 

});
```

I hope this helps.